# What is the name of the background pattern used in this banner work?

Tags: background

Hello i have searched the internet, at first i thought is a whirl but am now sure is not. Please what is that background pattern called and where do i get it please? Here is the picture: [image]

Comment: Draw it. It's for example a bunch of warped, originally straight and parallel rectangles.  Illustrator's Envelope Distortion bends and stretches them easily. Do not expect that someone here draws it for you as a ready to use file. If you need it online, hire from the web a designer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has a *name*. Not everything is named.

It's simply some "swirly lines" or "warped lines".

Comment: I need a way of getting it online

Comment: This isn't a research or "find it for me" service. Sorry, your searching is as good as anyone else's.